# Cakephp 3.7 - Auth Component: Get user in stateless authentication

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, stateless

When using a stateless authentication type (Basic or Digest), how can you access the user who was authenticated for the request?

With normal form authentication this is done with `$this->Auth->user()`, however when using Basic Authentication this always returns `null`, even when authentication was successful.

Comment: It works the same irrespective of the authentication type. Maybe you are invoking `user()` too early, or maybe you app unsets the data it at some point...

Comment: You are right, I was calling `user()` in `initialize()`, but apparently it is only available later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good hint from @ndm, I was calling `$this->Auth->user()` to soon: I am loading the Auth component in `AppController->initialize()`, but apparently the user info is only available afterwards.